Connecting a RTSP Stream to a HTTP/mp4 stream (Raspberry Pi)
Short question:
I have 2 cameras connected to my WiFi and a Raspberry Pi hosting a local website using Nginx. I want to connect these cameras and embed them into a html file, so I can view both of them live without any manual input.
More extensive:
So I have a camera system that lets me view the cameras live in either an app or by logging into their own local website. I can also use rtsp://user:password@ip:port/cam/realmonitor?channel=[1/2]&subtype=0 to access the livestream using VLC Media Player or another media player that supports rtsp streams. According to my research, there's no way to directly integrate rtsp into a html file, so I've tried converting them with VLC and tons of other methods, like
this stackoverflow post and a lot of websites, but none of them seem to work. VLC Conversion was the closest I could get, because I do in fact have access to the http stream, but when I try going there (http://ip:port/), it downloads the stream instead of playing it. I assume that's the reason why it isn't working on the website either, because it is when I use the same ip and port in VLC. I can't show any errors, since the video just keeps buffering and no actual errors appear. This leads to my question:
Is there a way to convert a (2) RTSP Stream(s) into a http stream and embed them into a website (live)?
I'm using:

Raspberry Pi (Raspbian OS)
Nginx
A RTSP stream

